# PHP recursive function bug?

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

I made this function to search inside nested array but I keep getting null for this array:

```
$arr3 = [
    'first' => 1,
    'second' => 2,
    'third' => [
        'fourth' => 4,
    ]
];

/**
 * returns the key for the first found value
 *
 * @param $needle
 * @param array $haystack
 * @return false|int|string
 */
function array_search_value($needle, array $haystack) {

    $result = null;
    $found = array_search($needle, $haystack);

    if ( $found !== false ) {
        // end the recursion
        $result = $found;

    } else {
        foreach ($haystack as $key => $item) {
            if (is_array($item)) {
                array_search_value($needle, $item);
            } else {
                continue;
            }
        }
    }

    return $result;
}

var_dump(array_search_value(4, $arr3));
```

I can't figure it out what have I done wrong?
The var_dump() result should be `string "fourth"`.

Comment: In the for-loop you need to assign result to the recursive call

Comment: When you call a function recursively you must make sure to propagate the recursive call's return value back to the original caller: return array_search_value($needle, $item);

Comment: Yes... you were right.... the return statement was missing in recursive call.... Please someone make an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you find the thing you're looking for during recursion you're not really storing it anywhere. Here's my recommended approach:

```
$arr3 = [
    'first' => 1,
    'second' => 2,
    'third' => [
        'fourth' => 4,
    ]
];

/**
 * returns the key for the first found value
 *
 * @param $needle
 * @param array $haystack
 * @return null|array
 */
function array_search_value($needle, array $haystack) {

    $result = null;
    $found = array_search($needle, $haystack);

    if ( $found !== false ) {
        // end the recursion
        $result = [ $found ]; //Array will make sense in a bit

    } else {
        foreach ($haystack as $key => $item) {
            if (is_array($item)) {
                $found = array_search_value($needle, $item);
                if ($found !== null) {
                   return array_merge([$key],$found);
                }
            } else {
                continue;
            }
        }
    }

    return $result;
}

var_dump(array_search_value(4, $arr3));
```

The reason for returning an array is in case the subarray has the same key as the main array so you would be able to consistently retrieve the correct key by recursively accesssing the array index for each array entry returned.

Check out the code at: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/085c949f660504010ed7ebb7a846e31b3a766d61

Here's an example as to why the returning of an array may be necessary:

If you consider the array:

```
$arr3 = [
    'a' => 1,
    'b' => 2,
    'c' => [
        'a' => 4,
    ],
    "d"=>[
        "a" => [
            "a" => 19    
        ]
    ]
];
```

If you're looking for 4 and not return an array you'll get back `a` but that will also be ambiguous because `a` contains 1 in the root array

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/43c2f2dfa197400df1e5748e12f12e5346abed3e

You could modify the above to get all paths that lead to the given result if there are more than one.

```
function array_search_value_all($needle, array $haystack) {

    $result = [];
    $found = array_search($needle, $haystack);

    if ( $found !== false ) {
        // end the recursion
        $result[] = [ $found ]; //Array will make sense in a bit

    } else {
        foreach ($haystack as $key => $item) {
            if (is_array($item)) {
                $found = array_search_value($needle, $item);
                if ($found !== []) {
                   $result[] = array_merge([$key],$found);
                }
            } else {
                continue;
            }
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

`array_search_value_all` will return an array of all paths leading to that value.

Example: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/fa4f5274703abb221f171c6e3ace5529594cdc8c

Comment: Something is wrong with your solution... I get an array with 2 values: `array (size=2)
  0 => string 'third' (length=5)
  1 => string 'fourth' (length=6)`

Comment: I guess it fine - he meant to return the whole path and not just the sub key. Nice one @apokryfos. Even if it is not what the OP meant :)

Comment: @dWinder actually in this answer you'll get the first path that leads to 4 . If you want to get all paths that lead to 4 that would be even more complicated. I'll try to provide an alternative that could get all

Comment: with apokryfs answer you can use the result to get the value directly from that nested array. for example I get the ['c', 'd'] and then it can be used to get that value programmatically

Comment: Just realised that so removed my commet

Comment: Not necessary to get all, that would be a completely different question.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing assign of the recursive call to you `$result`. You need to change:

```
if (is_array($item)) {
     array_search_value($needle, $item);
```

To: (notice that is the value not found keep searching and not just return)

```
if (is_array($item) ) {
    $i = array_search_value($needle, $item);
    if ($i)
        return $i;
```

Comment: it is enough just to write `return array_search_value($needle, $item);`!

Comment: Try case where `$arr = ["a" => ["b" => 1], "c" => ["d" => 4]]` and search for `4`

Comment: Glad to help. Notice @apokryfos answer which is also good - but I don't know what you need then just choose your output

Answer (score 1):

Just return the recursive call of `array_search_value` function:

```
    $arr3 = [
    'first' => 1,
    'second' => 2,
    'third' => [
        'fourth' => 4,
    ]
];

/**
 * returns the key for the first found value
 *
 * @param $needle
 * @param array $haystack
 * @return false|int|string
 */
function array_search_value($needle, array $haystack) {

    $result = null;
    $found = array_search($needle, $haystack);

    if ( $found !== false ) {
        // end the recursion
        $result = $found;

    } else {
        foreach ($haystack as $key => $item) {
            if (is_array($item)) {
                return array_search_value($needle, $item);
            } else {
                continue;
            }
        }
    }

    return $result;
}

var_dump(array_search_value(4, $arr3));
```

Comment: No good! what if the first array does not have the value but the second one has??

Comment: It will go recursively until it founds something... and if there is nothing it will return null

Comment: your question is a good base in case there are more than 1 array in depth

Answer (score 1):

When you call a function recursively you must make sure to propagate the recursive call's return value back to the original caller:

```
    $arr3 = [
    'first' => 1,
    'second' => 2,
    'third' => [
        'fourth' => 4,
    ]
];

/**
 * returns the key for the first found value
 *
 * @param $needle
 * @param array $haystack
 * @return false|int|string
 */
function array_search_value($needle, array $haystack) {

    $result = null;
    $found = array_search($needle, $haystack);

    if ( $found !== false ) {
        // end the recursion
        $result = $found;

    } else {

        foreach ($haystack as $key => $item) {
            if (is_array($item)) { 
               $target = array_search_value($needle, $item);
                if ($target){
                    return $target;
                }
            } else {
                continue;
            }
        }

    }
    return $result;
}

var_dump(array_search_value(4, $arr3));
```

Comment: No good! what if the first array does not have the value but the second one has??

Answer (score 0):

```
    $arr3 = [
    'first' => 1,
    'second' => 2,
    'third' => [
        'fourth' => 4,
    ]
];

/**
 * returns the key for the first found value
 *
 * @param $needle
 * @param array $haystack
 * @return false|int|string
 */
function array_search_value($needle, array $haystack) {

    $found = array_search($needle, $haystack);

    if ($found) {
        // put directly return here
        return $found;

    } else {
        foreach ($haystack as $key => $item) {
            if (is_array($item)) {
                return array_search_value($needle, $item);
            } else {
                continue;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What is you add in addition to existing answers?

Comment: Maybe, but it is not answer the OP problem